# Ввод данных через Scanner

Tags: java

Вот я написал код который вводит значения не в столбец а в строку:

```
  Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String scString2 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] scStrings2 = scString2.split(" ");
    int[] scNumbers2 = new int[powyk1];

    for(int i = 0; i < powyk1; i++) {
        if (Integer.valueOf(scStrings2[i])>0 && Integer.valueOf(scStrings2[i])<Math.pow(10,9)+7);
        scNumbers2[i] = Integer.valueOf(scStrings2[i]);
    }
```

Данные в массив вводятся следущим образом:

```
2 2 3 4 5 6
```

А как сделать что бы данные вводились попарно тоесть:

```
2 2
4 5
6 7
```

Comment: `;` - уберите во первых это после `if`

Comment: @Anton238 убрал

Comment: Можно сделать так: пользователь делает ввод - два_пробел_два - вы записываете его в string переменную с пом. nextLine, потом переносите в массив, удаляете средний элемент(можно присвоить первый и третий эл-ы в другой массив), и так три раза.

Comment: Используйте `nextint()` для всех. Будет намного проще

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець  можете кинуть пример

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int powyk1 = 6; // я задал вручную

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//        String scString2 = sc.nextLine();
//        String[] scStrings2 = scString2.split(" ");
        int[] scNumbers2 = new int[powyk1];

        for (int i = 0; i < powyk1; i++) {
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            if (num > 0 && num < Math.pow(10, 9) + 7)
                scNumbers2[i] = num;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scNumbers2));
    }
```

Comment: Нет вы не понимаете, я должне вводить две цифры в разних строках до конректного значение

Comment: т.е., когда встречаем значение `<= 0` или `>= Math.pow(10, 9) + 7`, нужно завершить ввод? Тогда добавьте `else break;`